# Find minimum distance ("Dist_km") for each Input ID to the TargetID, where minimum distance can be used only once

Tags: r, distance-matrix

I have a file with 945 unique InputIDs, and each of this InputID has a distance calculated to 1435 unique TargetIDs. I need to find a minimum distance to the TargetID to each InputID. The distance is calculated in the column "Dist_km" (see the data example attached).
The calculation needs to start from the lowest InputID (thus from 1 to 945 onwards). Important to note, that if once the minimum distance ("Dist_km") is found for the lower InputID, this can not be used again and next closest TargetID need to be assigned. That means, if InputID "3" and "6" is closest to the TargetID 93112261, then TargetID 93112261 is assigned to InputID "3", and other closest TargetID for "6" need to be found.

| InputID | TargetID | Dist_km |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 93112261 | 82.20803 |
| 1 | 93112285 | 73.93768 |
| 945 | 93263357 | 283.92473 |
| 945 | 92190485 | 129.49177 |

Comment: Hello, please share your data using ``dput()`` and do not share it as an image, as it makes it much harder for people to help you. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you! I will update it!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.